# Rails: Retrieve keys and values from hashmap

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, hashmap

I'm trying to retrieve two separate values with dates for a chart...

```
 @a = Applications.all.group_by_month(:created_at, format: '%b %y').count
 @b = Secondary_Applications.all.group_by_month(:created_at, format: '%b %y').count
```

I mapped it like this...

```
keys = [@a, @b].flat_map(&:keys).uniq

@ab_final = keys.map do |k| 
                {k => [{applications_one: @a[k] || 0}, 
                {applications_two: @b[k] || 0}]}
              end
```

This gives...

```
[
{"May 21"=>
  [{:applications_one=>20}, {:applications_two=>0}]},

{"Jun 21"=>
  [{:applications_one=>15}, {:applications_two=>0}]},

{"Jul 21"=>
  [{:applications_one=>8}, {:applications_two=>11}]},

 {"Aug 21"=>
  [{:applications_one=>1}, {:applications_two=>2}]} 
]
```

I don't know how to get the values from this point. How would you extract the date keys and values like...?

Expected output:

applications_one [20, 15, 8, 1]

applications_two [0, 0, 11, 2]

dates [May 21, Jun 21, Jul 21, Aug 21]

ty

Comment: What's input and what's expected output? Please edit your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you want to achieve?

```rb
arr = [
  {"May 21"=>
    [{:applications_one=>20}, {:applications_two=>0}]},

  {"Jun 21"=>
    [{:applications_one=>15}, {:applications_two=>0}]},

  {"Jul 21"=>
    [{:applications_one=>8}, {:applications_two=>11}]},

   {"Aug 21"=>
    [{:applications_one=>1}, {:applications_two=>2}]}
  ]

applications_one = []
applications_two = []
dates = []

arr.each do |hash|
  hash.values.flatten.each do |element|
    applications_one << element[:applications_one] if element.key?(:applications_one)
    applications_two << element[:applications_two] if element.key?(:applications_two)
  end
  dates << hash.keys.first
end

2.7.3 :027 > applications_one
 => [20, 15, 8, 1] 
2.7.3 :028 > applications_two
 => [0, 0, 11, 2] 
2.7.3 :029 > dates
 => ["May 21", "Jun 21", "Jul 21", "Aug 21"] 
2.7.3 :030 >
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it a bit different. Would start by structuring the data this way:

```
@ab_final = keys.map do |k| 
    {date: k, applications_one: @a[k] || 0, applications_two: @b[k] || 0}}
end
```

This should give you:

```
@ab_final = [
    {:date=>"May 21", :applications_one=>20, :applications_two=>0},
    {:date=>"Jun 21", :applications_one=>15, :applications_two=>0},
    {:date=>"Jul 21", :applications_one=>8, :applications_two=>11},
    {:date=>"Aug 21", :applications_one=>1, :applications_two=>2} 
]
```

And then you would get your expected outputs like this:

```
dates = @ab_final.map{|d| d[:date]}
=> ["May 21", "Jun 21", "Jul 21", "Aug 21"]

applications_one = @ab_final.map{|d| d[:applications_one]}
=> [20, 15, 8, 1]

applications_two = @ab_final.map{|d| d[:applications_two]}
=> [0, 0, 11, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your example array as follows:

```
arr = [
  {"May 21"=> [{:applications_one=> 20}, {:applications_two=>  0}]},
  {"Jun 21"=> [{:applications_two=>  0}, {:applications_one=> 15}]},
  {"Jul 21"=> [{:applications_one=>  6}, {:applications_three=>4}]},
  {"Aug 21"=> [{:applications_one=>  1}, {:applications_two=>  2}]}, 
  {"Sep 21"=> [{:applications_one=>  8}, {:applications_two=> 11}]},
  {"Oct 21"=> [{:applications_three=>7}, {:applications_one=>  1}]}
]
```

My purpose in doing so is to show that the code I suggest below:

- does not require the hashes within the values (arrays) of the date strings to be ordered;
- does not require the names of the keys of the hashes within the values (e.g., `:applications_one`) to be known in advance; and
- allows the values (arrays) of the date strings to contain any number of hashes.

---

The values of interest can be computed as follows.

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |g,h|
  date, a = g.flatten
  h[:dates] << date
  a.each do |f|
    label, value = f.flatten
    h[label] << value
  end
end
  #=> {
  # :dates=>["May 21", "Jun 21", "Jul 21", "Aug 21", "Sep 21", "Oct 21"],
  # :applications_one=>[20, 15, 6, 1, 8, 1],
  # :applications_two=>[0, 0, 2, 11],
  # :applications_three=>[4, 7]
}
```

---

The calculations proceed as follows.

Initially,

```
h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }
  #=> {}
```

The first hash is then passed to the block (held by the block variable `g`) and block operations are performed.

```
g = {"May 21"=> [{:applications_one=> 20}, {:applications_two=> 0}]}
```

```
date, a = g.flatten
  #=> ["May 21", [{:applications_one=>20}, {:applications_two=>0}]] 
  # therefore, date #=> "May 21" and
  # a #=> [{:applications_one=>20}, {:applications_two=>0}]]
```

See [Hash#flatten](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-flatten).

```
h[:dates] << date
  # now h #=> {:dates=>["May 21"]}
```

```
a.each do |f|
  puts "f=#{f}"
  label, value = f.flatten
  puts "label=#{label}, value=#{value}"
  h[label] << value
  puts "h=#{h}\n"
end
```

The following is displayed:

```
f={:applications_one=>20}
label=applications_one, value=20
h={:dates=>["May 21"], :applications_one=>[20]}

f={:applications_two=>0}
label=applications_two, value=0
h={:dates=>["May 21"], :applications_one=>[20], :applications_two=>[0]}
```

The next element of `arr` is now passed to the block and the block calculations are performed.

```
g #=> {"Jun 21"=> [{:applications_two=>  0}, {:applications_one=> 15}]}
```

```
date, a = g.flatten
  #=> ["Jun 21", [{:applications_two=>0}, {:applications_one=>15}]]
  # therefore, date #=> "Jun 21" and
  # a #=> [{:applications_two=>0}, {:applications_one=>15}]
```

```
h[:dates] << date
  # now h #=> {:dates=>["May 21", "Jun 21"]}
```

```
a.each do |f|
  puts "f=#{f}"
  label, value = f.flatten
  puts "label=#{label}, value=#{value}"
  h[label] << value
  puts "h=#{h}\n"
end
```

The following is displayed.

```
f={:applications_two=>0}
label=applications_two, value=0
h={:dates=>["May21", "Jun21"], :applications_one=>[20], 
   :applications_two=>[0, 0]}

f={:applications_one=>15}
label=applications_one, value=15
h={:dates=>["May21", "Jun21"], :applications_one=>[20, 15],
   :applications_two=>[0, 0]}
```

The remaining calculations are similar.

Note that when the second element of `arr` was passed to the block,

```
h #=> {:dates=>["May 21"], :applications_one=>[20],
  #    :applications_two=>[0]} g[:date] #=> "Jun 21"
```

the following calculation makes perfect sense:

```
h[:dates] << date
  #=> ["May 21"] << "Jun 21"
  #=> ["May 21", "Jun 21"]
```

By contrast, when the first element of `arr` was passed to the block, the following calculation was performed when `h #=> {}`, and therefore `h[:dates] #=> nil`:

```
h[:dates] << date
h #=> {:dates=>["May 21"]}
```

You might wonder why this works, since `nil` does not have a method `<<`. It's because of the way `h` was defined:

```
h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }
```

See the form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes a block (and therefore no argument).

What this means is that if `h` does not have a key `k` and may be altered by operation, the assignment `h[k] = []` is performed first. (This does not apply to, for example, `m = h[k]; m #=> nil`, as `h` is not being altered.)

After having processed

```
{"May 21"=> [{:applications_one=> 20}, {:applications_two=> 0}]}
```

the hash we are building is as follows:

```
h #=> {:dates=>["May 21"], :applications_one=>[20],
  #    :applications_two=>[0]}
```

---

For the example given in the question the following is returned:

```
{:dates=>["May 21", "Jun 21", "Jul 21", "Aug 21"],
 :applications_one=>[20, 15, 8, 1],
 :applications_two=>[0, 0, 11, 2]}
```

Comment: This is really nice and thanks for the concise descriptive reply. Really appreciated. I'll give this way a go!